# How do you dynamically return an implicitly set property in a CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, getter, cfc

I'm got a CFC whose properties I want to return through a single function:

```
public string function getApplicationSetting(required string setting)
{
    return myCFC.getSetting()
}
```

The problem is that `Setting` needs to be dynamic. If it were a struct, I could do this:

```
return myCFC.variables[arguments.setting]
```

In other words, the `Setting` in `getSetting()` needs to reflect the incoming argument. Am I approaching this wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: look into `<cfinvoke>` or `Evaluate()` for invoking function with dynamic function name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are in ColdFusion 8, you'll want to look at the onMissingMethod() function in ColdFusion.

Something like this **untested** example I just wrote up:

```
<cffunction name="onMissingMethod"> 
    <cfargument name="missingMethodName" type="string"> 
    <cfargument name="missingMethodArguments" type="struct"> 

    <cfif left(arguments.missingMethodName, 3) eq "get">
        <cfreturn variables[right(arguments.missingMethodName, len(arguments.missingMethodName)-3)] />
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

If you are in ColdFusion 9, then implicit getters are already a part of the deal if you define your properties correctly.

```
Component Person accessors=true {
    property firstname;
    property lastname;
    property age;
    property city;
    property state;
}
```

The above component will automatically have getLastname(), getFirstname(), etc.

Reference: http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/07/coldfusion-9-implicitgenerated-cfc-methods/